# sorting of strings by position of another string

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, sorting, search

What is the best way to do - Given a string A, and collection of strings C, order the strings in the collection in the non decreasing order of the position of A in the strings.

For instance,

```
A= abc
C= [deabc, abc, dabc, dad] 
Sorted C= [abc, dabc, deabc]
```

My idea is to iterate over the collection and put it in a HashMap/Dictionary with the position of A in C[i] as index. And then constructing the sorted collection from HashMap. This is not a homework problem. Just wanted to know the efficient way/algorithm of doing this. Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Can you make use of [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx)?

Comment: `var results = yourList.OrderBy(str=>str.IndexOf("abc"))`

Comment: What's the output when `C = [abc, dabc, dabd]`?

Comment: what about performance? if LINQ cannot be used, is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: @AustinSalonen, Sorted C given in the question is the output.

Comment: @AustinSalonen, sorry. output is C = [abc, dabc]

Comment: @Sam: LINQ is optimized.  If you use it correctly, it can be very efficient.  The question is not "is it efficient", but "is it fast enough" for your purpose.  You'll need to test this to know for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple way with LINQ:

```
var SortedC = C.OrderBy (d => d.IndexOf(A)).ToArray();
```

Note that strings not containing A will be sorted at the beginning because `IndexOf` returns `-1`.  Also, the behavior for strings with A at the same index is undefined, and will be returned in arbitrary order unless you provide a `.ThenBy` sort to handle those.

Comment: maybe you mean `d.IndexOf(a)` ?

Comment: If the strings are long maybe could be convenient to do: `var sorted = C.Select(x => new {Str=x,Pos=x.IndexOf(A)}).OrderBy(x => x.Pos).Select(x => x.Str);`

Comment: @mellamokb, is there a way to filter -1 values (a not found in d) in the order by clause?

Comment: Do you want to leave them out entirely?  If so, do `C.Where(d => d.IndexOf(A) != -1).OrderBy...`

Answer (score 1):

```
stringsArray.OrderBy(s => s.IndexOf("a"))
```